# wp_cronjob should run a special function

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a new wordpress plugins and I want to use the cronjob system from wordpress. But I get a little bit confused: Everytime the cronjob gets executed I want to run a special function. But the action will not be done. No post will be inserted.

The cronjob itselfs works correct. Maybe I do something wrong. (I manually tested the cron by opening the url `wp-cron.php?immo_import_check_import_folders`, and it shows me blank page. (Seems this is normal)

Code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'immo_import_activation');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'immo_import_deactivation');



function immo_import_activation() {

    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minutely', 'immo_import_check_import_folders' );
    add_action( 'immo_import_check_import_folders', 'immo_import_check_import_folders2' );
}


function immo_import_deactivation() {

    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('immo_import_check_import_folders');
}

function immo_import_check_import_folders2() {

    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'Test' ),
        'post_content'  => 'test .......',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
    );
    wp_insert_post($my_post); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `add_action` out of `immo_import_activation` function. If you need one time cron action, look into [`wp_schedule_single_event`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/)